# Check Session for all Controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After user logged in, a session will be set. I want to check the user session in all controllers (not all, but controllers which require a logged in user). In webforms we could do it in the page_load or using base classes. What's the recommended approach in asp mvc to do this? (I saw it would be a bad idea to use base controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a controller (check session in this) with inherit by `base controller` and refer this controller into your required controller.

BaseController:

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            //check Session here
        }
    }
```

DerivedController:

```
 public class ABCController : BaseController
    {
       //Your code
    }
```

Comment: Using base controllers in generally frowned upon. Action methods are generally used for functionality like this.

Comment: How can I authenticate in each action methods?

Comment: Before executing action `OnActionExecuting` will fire

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this.

You could create a custom authorization attribute inheriting from AuthorizeAttribute and do all your session and authorization code in one place, or

You could create your own Action Filter that does the necessary session checking and attach both attributes to the actions/controllers.

It depends on whether you would either want one or the other of these pieces of functionality to operate independently, if so, opt for the latter suggestion.

Comment: +1 for AuthorizeAttribute. In fact, he might not even need to derive a new class. The base AuthorizeAttribute may work on it's own.

Comment: Could you please provide example how we can achieve attaching attribute to controller. As when I apply the attribute, it does not work right. I am using IHttpContextAccessor in action filter class.