# Check Session on all actions of controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an simple MVC app 
I want to check first the session as this action

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Session["UserInfo"] == null)
            {
              return  RedirectToAction("Login", "Users");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

My question is about 
is there a way to enforce this check to all actions without do it manual for each action?

Comment: Have you tried adding `[Authorize]` attribute to all the relevant controllers?

Comment: No, How can I do this ?

Comment: Add the text `[Authorize]` before the controller definition...

Comment: is there another way which redirect to login?

Comment: There's lots of ways

Comment: Could you tell me one?

Comment: As @DavidG said,authorize is suitable, since you are coding in asp-mvc, but this method goes back to old asp.net webpages. Any how,@Usman gave you a good answer below. I suggest you to move your if(Session[...]) {...} block inside the constructor of your contorller class and see if it works for you(never tested this)

Comment: @Efe You cannot access session from inside the controller constructor, it's too early in the request life cycle.

Comment: @DavidG Good point,thanks, never thought about life cycle. I think FilterAttribute is the only solution for this.

Comment: This is exactly what @freelancer looking for, without using filter attributes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19293791

Answer (score 18):

you can use `OnActionExecuting` and can also override this method to write custom logic so create a class

```
 public class SessionCheck: ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
            if (session != null && session["UserInfo"] == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                                { "Controller", "Users" },
                                { "Action", "Login" }
                                });
            }
        }
    }
```

add namespaces in the class

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
```

and in your controller add `[SessionCheck]` attribute like this

```
 [SessionCheck]
 public class HomeController : Controller
  {
  }
```

this will check session on all the actions of controller or you can also add this attribute on action like this

```
[SessionCheck]
public ActionResult Index()
 {
 }
```